# Using nested class defined in a template inside nested class in inherited template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, syntax, inner-classes

I've written the following code:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_set>

namespace W {
  template<class Y, class Z> class A {
    public:
      class B : public std::enable_shared_from_this<B> {
        friend class A<Y, Z>;

        public:
          B() {  }
          void process() {  }
      };
  };
};



namespace U {
  class Mutex {
    std::mutex mutex;

    public:
      void lock()  {
        mutex.lock();
      }

      void unlock()  {
        mutex.unlock();
      }
  };

  template<class Y, class Z> class AA : public W::A<Y, Z> {
    public:
      class BB {
        public:
          private:
            Mutex B_mutex;
            std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<B>> B_list;
      }; 
  };
};
```

In short, I have a template definition (A) that has a nested class (B) that dose some processing. I have implemented another template (AA) that is based (inherited) the A template and it also has a nested class (BB) that has a list of pointers to (B) class.

When compiling I get the following error:

```
error: ‘B’ was not declared in this scope;
std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<B>> B_list GUARDED_BY(B_mutex);
                                   ^~
error: template argument 1 is invalid
std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<B>> B_list GUARDED_BY(B_mutex);
                                    ^~
```

I've taken a look 'Curiously recurring template pattern' as guidance but to no avail.

So is there a way to make this code work ?

Comment: please make the code a [mcve] if possible. It should be possible here. For example if `CAPABILITY("mutex")` is not relevant for the compiler error you can remove it from the code

Comment: fwiw, this is your code with non relevant parts removed and relevant parts added back in: https://godbolt.org/z/4e5855zWP.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this doesn't work is that in a class template that has a dependent base class (meaning a base class whose type depends on the template parameters of the class inheriting it), lookup for *unqualified* names doesn't search the dependent base class. So in order for the compiler to recognize `B`, it would need to be the case that `B` is a member of `BB` or `AA` itself or one of `AA`'s *non-dependent* bases, or an enclosing scope.

In order to force the compiler to find `B`, you must make it into a *qualified* name. An easy way to do this is to write `AA::B` instead of just `B`. Now the compiler knows that you mean a member of the current instantiation of `AA`, and it will search all of `AA`'s base classes for the name `B`, even the dependent ones.